# How do I repeat a function by putting the output from the previous time I ran the function as the input

Tags: python

```
k = np.log(2)/tSmall
N24Small = N0Small * math.exp(k*t)
k = np.log(2)/tBig
N24Big = N0Big * math.exp(k*t)
    SizeSmall = np.random.normal(meanSmall, sdSmall, int(N24Small)) 
SizeBig = np.random.normal(meanBig, sdBig, int(N24Big))
bigspeed = vcalc(SizeBig)
allSpeed = np.concatenate((smallspeed, bigspeed))
allSpeed.tolist()
allSpeed_hun = (allSpeed[0:99])
allSpeed_hun.tolist()
num_smallspeed = len(set(allSpeed_hun).intersection(smallspeed))
num_bigspeed = len(set(allSpeed_hun).intersection(bigspeed))
```

I have this function and I want to take the data from the last 2 variables and use it as the data for the variables N0small and N0 big

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a recursive function. I suggest you google "python recursive function" to read up on the details but the end result would look something like this:

```
def my_recursive_function(N0Small, N0Big):
    k = np.log(2)/tSmall
    N24Small = N0Small * math.exp(k*t)
    k = np.log(2)/tBig
    N24Big = N0Big * math.exp(k*t)
        SizeSmall = np.random.normal(meanSmall, sdSmall, int(N24Small)) 
    SizeBig = np.random.normal(meanBig, sdBig, int(N24Big))
    bigspeed = vcalc(SizeBig)
    allSpeed = np.concatenate((smallspeed, bigspeed))
    allSpeed.tolist()
    allSpeed_hun = (allSpeed[0:99])
    allSpeed_hun.tolist()
    num_smallspeed = len(set(allSpeed_hun).intersection(smallspeed))
    num_bigspeed = len(set(allSpeed_hun).intersection(bigspeed))
    
    # exit condition
    if (exit_condition):
        # i am taking a guess here
        return num_smallspeed, num_bigspeed
    return my_recursive_function(num_smallspeed, num_bigspeed)
```

You are going to need an exit condition so the function can stop calling itself. If the calculations you are doing are converging on to some value perhaps you can compare N0Small and num_smallspeed and exit if the difference between them is sufficiently small? I am just guessing here since I have no idea what this code is actually doing.